# TFS 2010, VS 2010 and convert branch to folder

Tags: visual-studio-2010, branch

I have created branches for one project, but now I have a need to modify branching.
Problem is that all I have in context menu (right click on project in source explorer), are branch and merge options. I have also tried to go to file-> source control-> Branching and Merging but I have same options (only two) as in context menu.

I have tried to add options in context menu for converting to folder from branch, but without result.

I tried tips from this forum: [convert to folder](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/7f92ca00-4798-4e08-8e1f-3be6effd5e6b/), but it didn't help me.

Where can I find that infamous "convert to folder" option for branch, in VS 2010?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The option should be available through the File menu only when you have selected a branch in the source control explorer.

Comment: I have tried this the way you described, but I still have no options in file->source control->branching and merging. When I do right click on that folder and go to properties from context menu, branching structure is showed on last tab, so it means that this folder is indeed branch.

Comment: The branching structure will also show for a folder that was previously a branch. You can also still branch/merge folders (instead of branches). You should be able to convert any folder to and from a branch. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181425.aspx for authorative documentation. What versions of VS and TFS are you using?

Comment: I'm using TFS 2010 and VS 2010. I have created branching structure, but I have no option to convert my branches back to folders.

Comment: Okay... to avoid any missing options in the GUI for whatever reason, you can use the power tools to convert your folder/branch from the command line: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/ (use the 'tfpt.exe branches /?' command)

Answer (score 0):

Make 100% sure you've properly synchronised via Check-In!  Check the list of items in your Team Explorer!1!

Then, thou shalt have convert to branch options.

^ Leaving here, because it actually CAN fix this reported problem.  Even with the down votes XP